# Publishing QGIS to intranet

Tags: qgis, web-mapping, qgis2web, lizmap

I have set up a basic QGIS project combining various WMS services and want to publish it to my company's intranet for everyone to use but I am a relative beginner at GIS and all the guides I have found are far too jargony or for previous versions so don't seem to apply.

I have tried the QGIS2Web plugin which was easy to use but didn't give me the popups, and the Lizmap plugin which I thought would be the answer but the user guide skims over uploading so having set it all up I can't work out how to get it from a QGIS file to something that is viewable on the web (presumably html?). By doing some Google searches I found a guide that suggested I needed Lizmap Web Client so I downloaded that but that was talking about putting it in Apache2 (whatever that is) rather than it just being something you install which confused me.

Can anyone direct me to a more beginners guide for creating a webmap on either of these platform? Specifically, is it possible to get QGIS2Web to show popups or is that just not going to happen? Or how do I get my Lizmap QGIS files on to my FTP in a format that is visible online?

Alternatively does anyone have any suggestions for a different approach to take?

Apologies if this seems a bit generic but I am a complete beginner so can't really be more specific than this!

I am using QGIS 3.8.2-Zanzibar, QGIS2Web 3.7.0, and Lizmap 3.1.3.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. What purpose should the webmap serve? Are people capable of using QGIS themselves? Does your intranet cover several sites of your company, or is there only one site (as in: how's the connection to your server for everyone) ?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] which emphasizes that there should be only one question asked per question.

Comment: A focused question that you could turn this one into is describing in detail what you tried and where you got stuck with one of the two plugins that you have tried.

Comment: Some more detail on the problem with popups in qgis2web would be helpful. Specifically, are you choosing Leaflet or OpenLayers for your export, and which layer type's popups are not working - do we assume WMS from your question? If so, you need to check the option `Enable GetFeatureInfo`. If you are still having problems, you should probably raise an issue at https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/issues/, where there are instructions on how to supply the info needed to solve a problem.

Comment: @Erik - Its just one site. No-one really knows how to use GIS hence trying to create an simple tool for them to use rather than just making the actual QGIS file communal (which is my plan B but its so slow to load I really don't want to have to resort to that if I can help it at all).

Comment: What are you trying to visualize for your colleagues?

Comment: @Erik - Its just a load of WMS datasets (geological etc) that I am trying to collect together in one place to make it easier to look at everything they need to in one place rather than having to go to 10 different websites to do it. I've kind of got it half working now. I'll have a bit of a play based on yours and Tom Chadwin's advice and see if I manage to get any further.

Comment: But you could create a slim QGIS-file (a subset), only containing these WMS and giving everyone access to it?

Comment: Sorry, I am lazy... efficient and always try to put in the least effort for the intended output.

Comment: @Erik - Its not the datasets per se its just QGIS in general. The software seems to take a long time to load in general its not the file thats the issue. Plus then everyone would have a install QGIS on their computers in order to use it etc. I'm trying to create a really pared down, simple, foolproof GIS that can just be shared and used without too much explanation involved.

Comment: @TomChadwin - Weirdly, only some of the datasets have the 'Enable GetFeatureInfo' checkbox and these datasets won't even show on the map through QGIS2Web, and the others will show on the map but don't have that checkbox despite seemingly being the same kind of dataset. But this gives me a good starting point to play around with so I'll be in touch on GitHub when I have worked out what the difference between the datasets is and a better idea of what the issue is. Thanks.

Comment: 'Enable GetFeatureInfo' should only appear on WMS layers. If nothing is displaying, the other option to check is "Match project CRS".